# How to set my GVim to be feel like IDE?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, text-editor, vim

Currently, I'm using GEdit as my text editor for editing Ruby and Javascript source codes. I would like to give GVim a try to be my editor choice. I have tried to follow https://github.com/akitaonrails/vimfiles and few others instructions, but I don't get any luck, when I source ~/.vimrc, then I always get:

```
bash: /home/samnang/.vimrc: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token (' 
bash: /home/samnang/.vimrc: line 5:call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()'
```

Could you point me somewhere to get the instruction or configuration?

Environment: Ubuntu 10.10

**Edit:** If I don't source it, when I type vim or gvim, then I got:

```
Vim: Caught deadly signal SEGV
Vim: Finished.
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Why are you sourcing the configuration file for vim? Let vim do that when it runs.

Comment: If it doesn't need it, but when I type vim or gvim I got: Vim: Caught deadly signal SEGV
Vim: Finished.
Segmentation fault

Comment: Then something is wrong with your vim install. How was vim installed? Via a package or from source. If from a package, install the "...-full" version. The source is always your final reference version though. It should compile easily for Ubuntu. I've installed vim on many flavors of Linux with no problems so I know it's easy to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`~/.vimrc` is the configuration file for vim, and will automatically be read by vim when it launches in order to know how you want it set up. You can add your non-graphical vim commands, such as key mappings, abbreviations to `~/.vimrc/`. In `~/.gvimrc` you can add commands to set your colorscheme, the default number of columns and rows displayed at startup, etc.

If you aren't familiar with vim itself type `vimtutor` at the command-line and go through the tutorial.

To start gvim, type `gvim` at the command-line. To edit a file you can either open gvim, then use `:e file/to/load` in comman-mode, or do `gvim file/to/load` at the command-line. gvim supports multiple windows and tabs as does vim, so study those things to make the most use of them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `source ~/.vimrc` as an Ex mode command. That is, inside Vim itself, hit `:` and enter the command:

```
:source ~/.vimrc
```

Right now, you're running Bash's `source` command, which is entirely not what you want to do.

Comment: You never need to do that inside vim unless you've made a change to it and need vim to inherit the change.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try integrating Vim with eclipse if you want to bring IDE functionality to Vim (like projects, error highlighting, code completion, etc).

If you're interested check out the **[eclim](http://eclim.org/)** project. It supports most of the modern languages, including Ruby, and I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a .vim or vimfiles in your $HOME directory. If it still fails, add a file to the .vim directory. I did a

```
cd
mkdir .vim
cd .vim
touch .netrwhist
chmod g+w .netrwhist
```

I discovered this while learning about building your own syntax files at [vim wikia creating your own syntax files](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Creating_your_own_syntax_files)