# Setting filenames in Tab

Tags: vim

Can someone tell me how to display filename in the tabs when I open several files using Vim?
Having a name on the tab would make changing to different files much easier.

Answer (score 8):

I think your question was "how do you display only the filename on your tab label". If that was the question, my answer is:

In a gui vim, you would use:

```
:set guitablabel=%t
```

However if's in vim, it gets a little more complicate. You have to overwrite the whole line, using :tabline. I modified the example provided in the [:help setting-tabline](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tabpage.html#setting-tabline), to add the behaviour you wanted. You would need to add the following code to your vimrc:

```
set tabline=%!MyTabLine()

function MyTabLine()
  let s = ''
  for i in range(tabpagenr('$'))
    " select the highlighting
    if i + 1 == tabpagenr()
      let s .= '%#TabLineSel#'
    else
      let s .= '%#TabLine#'
    endif

    " set the tab page number (for mouse clicks)
    let s .= '%' . (i + 1) . 'T' 

    " the label is made by MyTabLabel()
    let s .= ' %{MyTabLabel(' . (i + 1) . ')} '
  endfor

  " after the last tab fill with TabLineFill and reset tab page nr
  let s .= '%#TabLineFill#%T'

  " right-align the label to close the current tab page
  if tabpagenr('$') > 1 
    let s .= '%=%#TabLine#%999Xclose'
  endif

  return s
endfunction

function MyTabLabel(n)
  let buflist = tabpagebuflist(a:n)
  let winnr = tabpagewinnr(a:n)
  let label =  bufname(buflist[winnr - 1]) 
  return fnamemodify(label, ":t") 
endfunction
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I meant that when I open any file in vim ...instead of the tab saying vim on the top it should say the file name ...Is this code going to do that?I try to copy paste as is into my .vimrc and when I source .vimrc it gives me errors :
-bash: .vimrc: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: .vimrc: line 3: `set tabline=%!MyTabLine()'

Comment: What do you mean by open a file in vim? Like in a tab inside vim? Or when you from the terminal, open vim filename? That script, is for when you open a new tab, using tabnew, the label of that tab will be the filename(without the path).

Comment: On the other hand, you don't need to source the configuration file(vimrc). That's vim's job. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236299/how-to-set-my-gvim-to-be-feel-like-ide

Comment: Yes I meant the first case.So if I open a file a.c in vim and then do another tab within vim and open b.c the tab should show a.c and b.c ...like when you have multiple tabs in the browser you can differentiate each by its name ...I want something similar to that in vim....I copied what you gave.... its giving errors.The only other line above this was "syntax on" in the .vimrc

Comment: Which errors appear when you open vim? Im using Vim 7.2.330 in ubuntu maverick, and I get no errors. Its strange, because its an example from the help from vim. I just modified one line.

Comment: ~ $source .vimrc  
-bash: syntax: command not found  
-bash: .vimrc: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: .vimrc: line 2: `set tabline=%!MyTabLine()'

Comment: and i first tried to open a new file in vim after adding this to .vimrc ..it didnt show file name ..then I source .vimrc ..and it showd the above errors.....mine is   version 7.2.108  on snow leopard

Comment: Thanks a ton for your solution. I had vim, not gvim.. thanks again